# Sublime Text 3 cannot support nesC language Syntax Highlighting

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, nesc

1. Sublime Text 3 editor has been installed in Window10 OS, i get a package named nesC.tmbundle (from https://github.com/cdwilson/nesC.tmbundle) that can support nesC syntax highlighting in Mac and Linux platform, but it cannot make the nesC language syntax highlighting in Window10.
2. there are two critical files in nesc.tmbundle package used to support syntax highlighting, one is *info.plist* and another is *Syntaxes/nesC.tmLanguage*, maybe the two files can not be parsed correctly in window10 platform. maybe i should do some adjustments for the two files, but i cannot understand them deeply, so ask for help from who can undetstand it. thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried just using `Package Control: Add Repository` from the Command Palette, pasting in `https://github.com/cdwilson/nesC.tmbundle`, and then `Package Control: Install Package` `nesC.tmbundle`?

Comment: I have tried, it can be installed successfully, but it always supports C language syntax highlighting(nesC cover the most keyword and Syntax of C language), but cannot support nesC‘s own syntax highlighting.

Comment: ah I see, it [includes the C syntax definition](https://github.com/cdwilson/nesC.tmbundle/blob/d0d322ceafe3c4d8affc0e8b767fb6ad65c52704/Syntaxes/nesC.tmLanguage#L17-L18) - maybe it's not working because the C syntax has been updated, and nobody has maintained the nesC syntax to ensure that it is still compatible.

Comment: I try to comment the code from Line 16 to Line 19 in nesC.tmLanguage which is from the Syntax directory in this Repository, and then the nesC's own syntax highlighting can be supported, but the C language syntax highlighting cannot be supported.